# Probability of maximum degree in On random graphs I by Erdos

Tags: graph-theory, probability-distributions, combinations, algebraic-graph-theory, random-graphs

In [The Maximum Degree of a Random Graph](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=971196) by RIORDAN et al., the authors commented that the study of the distribution of the maximum
degree $d^{max}(G)$ of  a random graph $G$ was started by Erdos and Renyi  in [On random graphs I](http://ftp.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1959-11.pdf).

I failed to identify the discussion in that paper by Erdos et al. It contains the proofs of four theorems none of them on $d^{max}(G)$.

The only relevant thing I can infer is from the first theorem.

[image]

So, $d^{max}(G) = n-1$ for a completely connected graph. In that sense the probability of being $d^{max}(G) = n-1$ should be same as the probability in the theorem above.

Was this what RIORDAN et al. was referring to?

PS. The only problem is that in a completely connected graph the number of edges is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ but Erdos assumed the number of edges to be $[\frac{1}{2}n \log n + c n]$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: By "completely connected" they meant that all vertices belong to the same connected component, not that the graph is a clique. This is indeed the threshold of connectivity for $G(n,p)$.

Comment: @Graffitics, you mean $e^{-e^{-2c}}$?

Comment: Yes, with $N_c= [1/2 n \log n + cn]$.

Comment: I couldn't aceess the Riordan et al. paper, but at a quick glance it doesn't seem that the maximal degree of $G(n,p)$ was studied in this particular paper. However this paper is commonly seen as the start of random graphs, and it is also likely that they started the analysis of $d^{max}$ in another old paper. Do you have a precise quote or a link to the pdf?